# JQuery Multiple Checkbox Groups Validation

Tags: jquery, validation, checkbox

How can I validate Checkbox groups with JQuery? I need to make sure that in each group at least one checkbox is selected. I'd like to use a class to identify the groups, so, the html would look like this:

```
<!-- checkbox group -->
<fieldset class="CbxGroup">
  <legend>Checkbox Group (required)</legend>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="cbxGroup1[]" value="one" id="cbxGroup1_0">One </label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="cbxGroup1[]" value="two" id="cbxGroup1_1">Two </label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="cbxGroup1[]" value="three" id="cbxGroup1_2">Three</label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="cbxGroup1[]" value="four" id="cbxGroup1_3">Four </label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="cbxGroup1[]" value="five" id="cbxGroup1_4">Five </label>
  <br>
</fieldset>
```

Because checkboxes don't have a wrapper element like the select list/menu, I don't know how to pull this off. For single checkboxes I can do something like the following but it does not work for checkbox groups:

Thank you!

```
$('.CbxSingle').each(function() {
        var CbxCheck = $(this);
        if(!CbxCheck.is(':checked')) {
            // do something
        }
        else{
            // do something else
        }
    });
```

I'd like something like the following that would validate each group separately:

```
$('.CbxGroup').each(function() {
        if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0) {
            alert('not selected!');
        }
        else{
            alert('selected!');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this might work:

```
if($(".CbxSingle input[type=checkbox]:checked").length != 0){
    // Run success code
}else{
    // Run failure code
}
```

There is actually a very similar reference on the jQuery documentation website for the :checked selector: http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed. I thought this was going to be very complicated but it turned out to be so simple.

Comment: Oops! I spoke too early. If I add another checkbox group, it validates them as a single group rather two separate ones. Any idea how I can teak it so it validates each group separately?

Comment: $('.mcCbxGroup').each(function() {
   if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0) {
          alert('not selected!');
      }
      else{
    alert('selected!');
   }
  });

Comment: Hmm, try this as the selector: $('.CbxSingle input[type=checkbox][name="cbxGroup1[]"]:checked')

Answer (score 2):

This might work for what you describe:

```
var numberChecked=$("input[name='cbxGroup1[]']:checked").length;
if(numberChecked<1)
    alert('none checked');
else
    alert(numberChecked+' checked);
```

Comment: This would also allow you to have multiple groups of checkboxes, just change the name of the checkboxes and you can reuse the code throughout your form.

Comment: I don't think this would work. I need to identify the groups with the class name. That means I need to identify all the checkboxes within a group and make sure that at least one is selected. That way I can have multiple groups and have all of them validated the same way without writing code for each group separately.

Comment: You can change the name for all the groups.  So this is for cbxGroup1[], if you have a cbxGroup2[], then make another variable for those that are checked.  Here is a fiddle for you to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Ygcc8/

Comment: Hi, What I'd like is to not having to write new code for each checkbox group. Just one validator that allows me to place multiple checkbox groups on the form and have all of them validated separately. I'd like to validate each group, not each checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I created a slight [variation as a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bewee/), and it seems to work fine. I think your problem is the `.CbxSingle` class isn't applied to the `input`s, so you might use a different selector like `.CbxGroup input[type=checkbox]`.

Comment: The code above for single checkboxes works fine. It isn't for checkbox groups which is what I need so I can have multiple groups without writing separate code for each.

Comment: Try replacing `$('.CbxSingle')` in your JavaScript snippet with `$('.CbxGroup input[type=checkbox]')`.