# Validate Multiple Groups of checkboxes in the same form jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am pretty new to jQuery and I need to have at least one checkbox checked in a group of checkboxes of the same form. here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KL4ck/)

HTML:

```
<form>
    <!-- CHECKBOX GROUP NUMBER ONE -->
     <h3>group one</h3>

    <input type="checkbox" class="reqNow" name='part1'>
    <input type="checkbox" class="reqNow" name='part1'>
    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- CHECKBOX GROUP NUMBER TWO -->
     <h3>group two</h3>

    <input type="checkbox" class="reqNow" name='part2'>
    <input type="checkbox" class="reqNow" name='part2'>
    <!-- CHECKBOX GROUP NUMBER THREE -->
     <h3>group three</h3>

    <input type="checkbox" class="reqNow" name='part3'>
    <input type="checkbox" class="reqNow" name='part3'>
    <!-- CHECKBOX GROUP NUMBER FOUR -->
     <h3>group four</h3>

    <input type="checkbox" class="reqNow" name='part4'>
    <input type="checkbox" class="reqNow" name='part4'>
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var submitOK = false;


$("form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();


    var a = $(".reqNow").serializeArray();

    $.each(a, function (i, b) {
        if (b.value == "on") {
            submitOK = true;
        }


        if (submitOK) {
            alert("Form Sent!");
        }
    });

});
```

so basically I want the form to send only when there is at least one checkbox checked in each group.

any help is appreciated!

Comment: your code is fine you can add extra checks to see if the `if (b.name == "part1")` `if (b.name == "part2")` etc..

Answer (score 1):

You can check analogous to this answer [JQuery Multiple Checkbox Groups Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8621588/1741542)

```js
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var g1 = $('.reqNow[name=part1]:checked').length;
    var g2 = $('.reqNow[name=part2]:checked').length;
    var g3 = $('.reqNow[name=part3]:checked').length;
    var g4 = $('.reqNow[name=part4]:checked').length;
    if (g1 > 0 && g2 > 0 && g3 > 0 && g4 > 0)
        alert('Form sent!');
});
```

See modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KL4ck/1/)